# How to rectify the error "No value given for one or more parameters"

Tags: excel, vba

I'm new to VBA and using guidance from internet I have tried this. I'm trying to update range of cell in column 'K' to YES or NO against each cell value in column K, when a range of cell value with column name [OUTPUT$].[Scanned KD serial no] matches with another range of cell value with column name [OUTPUT$].[KD serial].

```
 Sub CHECK_DATA()
 Dim sSQLQry As String
 Dim ReturnArray
 Dim Conn As New ADODB.Connection
 Dim mrs As New ADODB.Recordset
 Dim DBPath As String, sconnect As String
 Dim i As Integer
 DBPath = ThisWorkbook.FullName
 sconnect = "Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Data Source=" & DBPath _
& ";Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=Yes;IMEX=1"";"
Conn.Open sconnect

sSQLSting = "SELECT [OUTPUT$].[Scanned KD serial no],[OUTPUT$].[KD serial] From [OUTPUT$] where [OUTPUT$].[Scanned KD serial no]=[OUTPUT$].[KD serial]" ' Your SQL Statement (Table Name= Sheet Name=[Sheet1$])"

mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn

    i = 3
Do Until mrs.EOF
    If [OUTPUT$].[Scanned KD serial no] = [OUTPUT$].[KD serial] Then
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "K").Value = "YES"

    Else
    Worksheets("Output").Cells(i, "K").Value = "NO"
    End If
i = i + 1
mrs.MoveNext
Loop
mrs.Close
Conn.Close
End Sub
```

When I run the above code its showing error "No value given for one or more parameters" in the line "mrs.Open sSQLSting, Conn".

Suggest me how to rectify this error.

[image: Screenshot of the worksheet]

Comment: You get this error because your SQL statement cannot be executed

Comment: post a sample data of the sheet and most likely we can figure it  out

Comment: I have added the screenshot of the worksheet, is it ok for you?

Comment: Comparing your SQL to the screen-shot I see a discrepancy in at least one field name. You've used a period in the worksheet after "no": `no.` but the period is missing in the SQL statement each time you use the field name.

Comment: Hi all Thanks a lot for giving your valuable time, I have got the result